# Does rewrite url affect the url in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess

i was trying to use filename in jQuery i'm facing problem file not found was it because of rewrite file?when i tried using full url it worked fine..

> **I tried this it did not work**

```
 $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'inentry.php',
                        data: $("#myform").serialize(),
                        success:function(data)
                        {

                        }
                    });
```

> **i tried this and this work**

```
 $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'http://localhost/mgosoft/admin/inentry.php',
                            data: $("#myform").serialize(),
                            success:function(data)
                            {

                            }
                        });
```

why i'm not able to access the file directly ? is there a problem with my htaccess file?

> .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mgosoft/admin/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+mgosoft/admin/index\.php\?p=([^\ &]+)&?([^\ ]*)

RewriteRule ^ /mgosoft/admin/%1/?%2 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: http://community.sitepoint.com/t/htaccess-redirect-all-urls-except-some-and-exclude-my-own-ip/7382/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your local version add

```
<base href="//localhost/mywebsite" />
```

to the head section

and for your live versions change it to

```
<base href="//your.domain.here" />
```

reference at http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.4